# Where can I find older versions of PlantUML documentation?

Tags: plantuml

I found a pdf containing all the information I need, unfortunately it is (currently) for version 1.2019.6 http://plantuml.com/guide

I'm currently using 1.2019.3, and can't upgrade because the changes to preprocessing break my project, where can I find a similar helpful PDF but for version 1.2019.3(or older versions in general)?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them at plantuml@gmail.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find something interesting here:

http://pdf.plantuml.net/1.2019.3/PlantUML_Language_Reference_Guide_en.pdf

:-)

And we are interested by the issue you have with the new preprocessor. Maybe we can fix them ? So tell us more about it... Thanks

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!!  The only issue is that we have quite a few `!definelong FOO` macros for example, and we don't have the time to upgrade them for a while.  But with this we should be covered for documentation until we get a chance to upgrade :>